# A line appears when using the brush

Tags: texturing

basically this weird line appears when using the brush. I am still a newby and most probably I pressed a shortcut accidentally. Can anyone help me?

[image: the line is in the brush circle]

Comment: You turned on *Stabilize Stroke*. It's a brush setting. See the answer for Blender 2.8 linked above.